# ServiceStack OrmLite for Oracle hangs during select

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I am trying ServiceStack OrmLite (with Oracle database). But it just hangs at `db.Select`.. it is not throwing exception either.. it just hangs there as if there are too many data to load.

**I have installed the latest oracle instant client ver 12.1 in my PC.**

This is my OrmLite code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
            static void Main(string[] args) {
            string DbConnection = 
                "SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=9530))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYSID)));uid=myusername;pwd=mypassword";

            var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
                DbConnection, false, OracleDialect.Provider);

            using (var db = dbFactory.Open()) {
                var res = db.Select<Einduk>().Take(10);  //<-- it hangs here, no stacktrace whatsoever
                foreach (var einduk in res) {
                    Console.WriteLine(einduk.ToString());
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my model class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Einduk
    {           
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string Akaun { get; set; }
        public string Jenis { get; set; }
        public string Bakaun { get; set; }
        public string Oldac { get; set; }
        public string Plgid { get; set; }
        public string Pnama { get; set; }
        public string Almat { get; set; }
        public string Kslah { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Trikh { get; set; }
        public decimal? Amaun { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() {
            return string.Format("Jenis: {0}, Akaun: {1}, Bakaun: {2}, Oldac: {3}, Plgid: {4}, Pnama: {5}, Almat: {6}, Kslah: {7}, Trikh: {8}, Amaun: {9}", Jenis, Akaun, Bakaun, Oldac, Plgid, Pnama, Almat, Kslah, Trikh, Amaun);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my table, note that **the table does not have a primary key**. But in my model I set `Akaun` as the primary key as I know it is unique. **Will this cause the problem?**

```
CREATE TABLE "EINDUK" 
(   
    "JENIS" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "AKAUN" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE), 
    "BAKAUN" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "OLDAC" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "PLGID" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "PNAMA" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "ALMAT" VARCHAR2(282 BYTE), 
    "KSLAH" VARCHAR2(508 BYTE), 
    "TRIKH" DATE, 
    "AMAUN" NUMBER
)
```

Comment: I suspect I am not supposed to use `.Take()`... hmm... any clue how to limit the number of rows returned?

Comment: Nevermind.. I am supposed to use `db.select<Einduk>("rownum < 10")` instead of `.Take()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a Select().Take(10), you are trying to load all the data in the memory and then try to get the first 10 records from the (in-memory)list. Instead using Select without parameter, try this

```
  SqlExpressionVisitor<Einduk> ev = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.ExpressionVisitor<Einduk>();
  ev = ev.Limit(0,10);
  var res = db.Select<Einduk>(ev);
```

In order to understand the features of Ormlite, read the README.md file :

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of `SqlExpressionVisitor`. Is there any advantage of using this as opposed of doing like this `db.select<Einduk>("rownum < 10")` ? I assume using `SqlExpressionVisitor` will ensure my code is not database dependent?

Comment: If you are just going to use Oracle then, No. But if you want to switch to other database this code does not works- when you are using the ormlite, the framework uses the appropriate code for wrapping the paged result sql - for example if you want to get the first 10 rows in Sql Server, the framework uses "Top 10" in your select automatically.